# How to load ajax from a controller function in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, notifications, gritter

I am making a codeigniter application and in this application there is a function load_notification which runs below loop. In loop when the if condition return true then notification popup should appear to user.

I am using [gritter notification jquery.](http://boedesign.com/demos/gritter/)

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    if($record == 1) {
        // Show notification popup to user.
    }

}
```

So can somebody tell me how to achive this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "write my code for me" question

Comment: in the if load the view and return it as the ajax response. Then load the content in the success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In echo statement write your script and add `break;`
It will show your alert if the condition is satisfied.

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    if($record->columnName == 1) {
         // Show notification popup to user.
         echo "<script>alert('your Notification Message!!')</script>";
         break;
    }
}
```